# RSpec - The passwords in my test are not matching up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, authentication, rspec

I wrote up a test that should describe the case where @user and found_user should be the same  via password match. This also describes when they're different. I'm not using devise or anything, but rather building out my own authentication with `has_secure_password`

```
describe "return value of authenticate method" do
  before { @user.save }
  let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

  describe "with a valid password" do
    it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
  end

  describe "with an invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate('invalid') }

    it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
  end
end
```

The part that's failing is `with a valid password` block. The error message clearly shows that `password_digest` isn't matching up

Here's the relavent output:

```
expected: password_digest: "$2a$04$cDKhuWzsZuW8Gm4t5fJjpu6rmbwh10ZAt2Yae.BO0iuD...">
got: password_digest:      "$2a$04$jwfHjoLI0RpDIAEr9SMKGOZqeH.J5ILOkzalKCYQdDW4...">
```

I've attempted removing the @user.save in the before block thinking that might solve it, but it didn't.

I'm not really sure why they're coming up differently or what it is that I'm doing wrong. I'm fairly new to rspec and testing in general.

I should mention that my authenticate method is working in the rails console. So I have a situation where the application code works, but the tests are failing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My user class is here: https://gist.github.com/DavidVII/f190d1f1e114234bb7d7

Thnx!

Comment: Have you removed some code? I cannot see your `subject` block that will tell me what `it` is . . . that might be relevant to your error message.

Comment: Here's the full user_spec.rb file if you're interesting in checking that out. https://gist.github.com/DavidVII/f190d1f1e114234bb7d7

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look. Not a bad start. One slightly confusing thing about the code is the mismatch between the `describe` and `it` blocks and the `subject`. You don't have to make `describe` match `subject`, but it really helps others to read your tests. I think however, that's a topic for a different question. As is perhaps how you are isolating the test database (your test results give me the suspicion that you may not have a completely clean test db).

Comment: Indeed. I am fairly new to testing, so thanks for your advise on mismatching. I'm using postgres for my database and I feel like it's been more trouble than it's worth, but I really want the same database locally that I'm running on stage (heroku). How would I go about cleaning up my test database?

Comment: Okay, so this is weird. I cleaned out my database and and rebuilt it using db:schema:load and db:test:prepare. This resulted in my test passing, but if I run it again. It'll fail. I feel like I'm missing something totally obvious here, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Your test is leaving behind the test user, and possibly other items in the database. The reason why the passwords are different is because your test generates *another* test user, and tries to compare it with the one from the previous test. To fix this, your test needs to rebuild the database prior to each run - this is easiest to setup in the `Rakefile`. Important: Make sure the tests are coded so that you don't have a chance of re-building a production database! If you are not sure about that, please ask a new question about it on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test won't work with bcrypt password hashing (I can tell this what you are using from the form of the string), as it generates a new random salt for each password change. This is a good thing, don't alter that behaviour.

So you should not write tests that look for stored passwords being equal to known values. It is not 100% clear if you intended that in the test, or have accidentally over-simplified the test due to all the abstraction you get though using `has_secure_pasword`, or some other thing has led you to the current code.

Instead, your tests around password handling should be more black box, and assert that you *can* log in with the known password, and not login with any others (including code-breaking cases such as nils, empty strings, super-long passwords and a string which matches the hashed password).

Comment: Indeed I am using bcrypt. This makes a whole lot of sense, but I'm pretty new to rspec and testing in general so I don't really know how to appraoch it. What you gave me is good enough to go off of though. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if I can write a test that can authenticate the user variable. Something like `@user.authenticate('foobar')` then make sure that that is valid.

Comment: Reason I unchecked this was because the Rails Tutorial Book (rails 4 edition) does it the way I did and it passes. The only difference here is that I'm using postgres instead of sqlite for my local instance. Obviously, this has something to do with my database and I'm not sure what. I can't get my test to pass no matter what I do. Again, it might be because I'm new to testing and may not be doing things right.

Comment: This is technically the correct answer since in doing this we found another issue with my database. Perhaps a new post in SO is in order. Thanks, Neil!

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "with an invalid password" do 
 let(:@user_for_invalid_password) { found_@user.authenticate('invalid') }
 it { should_not eq @user_for_invalid_password }
 specify { expect(@user_for_invalid_password).to be_falsey}
 end
end
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.